# How do I mock a class with initialized methods using Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, double

I am trying to practice using doubles and mocking in my Rspec tests in order to isolate my dependencies. At the moment I am making a simple banking program that has 2 classes - an Account class, responsible for the transaction logic such as updating balance, crediting, debiting etc. I also have a Statement class, responsible for formatting a bank statement based on the account transaction history.

My Account class is initialized as follows:

```
def initialize(statement = Statement.new)
    @balance = 0.00
    @credit = ''
    @debit = ''
    @date = Date.today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    @transaction = []
    @statement = statement
end
```

My Statement class is iniitalized as follows:

```
  def initialize
    @display = []
  end
```

(The display array is an array of transaction arrays, which are all the transactions that have occurred in that particular account).

In my statement_spec.rb file, I want to use a double of the Account class. How do I set up an Account double that already has a Statement with a full display? At the moment I have:

`account = double(Account.new(statement = statement))` but I want to make sure that the display has transactions in them so I can test the Statement class methods with an a fake, functioning account?

Sorry if I haven't explained that very clearly. Struggling to get my head around mocking so any help is really appreciated! Thanks :)

UPDATE: 
The method I am testing is this:

```
  def format
    puts 'date || credit || debit || balance'
    @display.map do |transaction|
      return @display.join(' || ')
    end
  end
```

And the current test is this:

```
  describe '#format' do
    it 'prints the statement as a table' do
      account = Account.new
      account.deposit(15.00)
      account.complete_transaction
      expect(account.statement.format).to eq Date.today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + ' || 15.00 ||  || 15.00'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but at the moment I see no reason the mock an `account` in a `statement_spec` because the statement in your example has no association to an account. In an `account_spec` it might make sense to mock `Statement` or you simply can assign `nil` – that depends on the method you try to test. Can you please add an example of the method that you actually want to test and how the test should look like?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I think you're probably right! I have updated my post with the method and the test as it is currently.

Comment: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-with-rspec-doubles-and-expectations should help you figure out what you should and shouldn't use doubles for

Answer (score 0):

Your test does much more than it says it does. It only expect the string to hace certain format but it does extra work. I would test different things:

your statement_spec.rb

```
describe '.format' do
  it 'returns the statement as a table' do
    statement = Statement.new
    statement.display = [15.00, 0, 15.00]
    expect(statement.format).to eq Date.today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + ' || 15.00 ||  || 15.00'
  end
end
```

and on your account spec (I don't know your actual code, it's just to give you the idea of splitting the specs)

```
describe 'it sets statement display values' do
  account = Account.new
  account.deposit(15.00)
  expect(account.statement.display).to include 15.00
end
```

Now the statement spec does not care about accounts, and the account spec related to de statement has a real statement to work with.